# How can i define an ActionScript event handler function inline in AddEvent Listener

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have an action listener :

```
myText.addEventListener(TextEvent.LINK,linkClickHandler);
```

As according to this, i need to write an event handler function seperate to handle the text link event.

Now my requirement is i need to write that function in the same line isntead of giving its name.ie, something like

```
mytext.addEventListenet(TextEvent.LINK, 
                 function(event:TextEvent) {....code comes here....});
```

can i do like this in AS3.What will the syntax for this if possible.

Also i want to know, wether i can pass one more extra param to the event handler other than event which is the default parameter.

Comment: Sorry for the vague comment, but I once read that there was a bug with this. Can anybody verify that?

Comment: Depending on the specific case, you have to make sure your dynamic function doesn't get garbage collected before it's invoked. Usually, you're better off registering the function somehwere.

Comment: my probelm is i need to pass a parameter to the event handler while declaring it in action listner.If i am able to do that, i can define the handler somewhere else also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code will work. Just need a return type on the function.

EDIT: A simple delegate class:

```
public class Delegate
{

    public var cb:Function;
    public var args:Array;

    public function Delegate(cb:Function, ...args)
    {
        this.cb = cb;
        this.args = args;
    }

    public static function create(cb:Function, ...args):Function {
        var functionProxy:Delegate = new Delegate(cb, args);
        return functionProxy._create;
    }

    public function _create(e:Object=null):void {
        var params:Array = new Array();
        if(e) {
            params.push(e);
        }

        for each (var o:Object in args[0]) {
            params.push(o);
        }
        cb.apply(null, params);
    }

}
```

Comment: can i pass one extra parameter to the function while declaring in action listener

Comment: You'll need to do something like a Delegate class: http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/205/1/The-Delegate-Class/Page1.html.

Comment: That's a great reference. thanks buddy. Also the code worked inline as well. Now i have two good options. Cool

Comment: Actually, that example is old and not exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way exist like "addEventlistener(handlerName,{parameters},..). If  that is possible, thats the best.

Comment: Maybe if you created a custom event class that allows for extra parameters, like the one here: http://evolve.reintroducing.com/2007/10/23/as3/as3-custom-events/

Comment: @letseatfood: that's slightly different. That's attaching variables to the event itself, but you can't control most of the events (e.g., MouseEvent) so one way is to bind additional arguments onto the function.